# Why do node modules have an `@` in the name?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

With the release of `material-ui` version 1, I noticed they have added an `@` symbol to the front of the library name `@material-ui/core`. After digging into my node modules, I see that they aren't the only one - I have `@babel` and `@types` as well.

Is the `@` significant for some reason, or is it just for the purposes of clarity and avoiding conflicts with previous versions of the library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@ indicates that the package is a scoped package. It is a way of grouping similar projects under single scope. A scoped package can be published as private as well as public. For more info check out the following link [npm-scope](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope)